# Why is my imported module grayed out in PyCharm but still needed to run?

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and I don't understand why the module I imported `from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D` is grayed out in `PyCharm`. If I run the program without it, I get errors. I'm sure there are plenty of things wrong with what I'm doing in this program. I'm just trying to get a contour graph of a specific function and a surface plot. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  <---- Grey
import numpy as np
from numpy import arange
from pylab import meshgrid, imshow, contour, colorbar, show
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Graphs(object):

    def z_func(self, x, y):
        return -x*y*(np.exp(-(np.square(x))-(np.square(y))))

    def contour_graph(self, x_c, y_c):
        x_two, y_two = meshgrid(x_c, y_c)
        z = self.z_func(x_two, y_two)
        im = imshow(z, cmap=cm.RdBu)
        contour(z, arange(-1, 1.5, 0.01), linewidths=1, cmap=cm.Set3)
        colorbar(im)
        show()

    def surface_plot(self, x_s, y_s):

        x_s2, y_s2 = meshgrid(x_s, y_s)
        z_s = self.z_func(x_s2, y_s2)
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        surf = ax.plot_surface(x_s2, y_s2, z_s, rstride=1, cstride=1,
                       cmap=cm.RdBu, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

        ax.zaxis.set_major_locator(LinearLocator(10))
        ax.zaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.02f'))
        fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)
        plt.show()

g = Graphs()

x_func = arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.01)
y_func = arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.01)

#c = g.contour_graph(x_func, y_func)
g.surface_plot(x_func, y_func)
```

These are the errors I am getting when I take out the module:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\cwoyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\projections__init__.py", line 65, in get_projection_class
>       return projection_registry.get_projection_class(projection)
>     File "C:\Users\cwoyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\projections__init__.py", line 29, in get_projection_class
>       return self._all_projection_types[name]
>     KeyError: '3d'
>     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/cwoyt/PycharmProjects/graph/graph_2.py", line 44, in 
>       g.surface_plot(x_func, y_func)
>     File "C:/Users/cwoyt/PycharmProjects/graph/graph_2.py", line 29, in surface_plot
>       ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
>     File "C:\Users\cwoyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1368, in gca
>       return self.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\cwoyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1002, in add_subplot
>       self, *args, **kwargs)
>      File "C:\Users\cwoyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\projections__init__.py", line 98, in process_projection_requirements
>       projection_class = get_projection_class(projection)
>     File "C:\Users\cwoyt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\projections__init__.py", line 67, in get_projection_class
>       raise ValueError("Unknown projection '%s'" % projection)
>      ValueError: Unknown projection '3d'

Right now this program is the only one in the folder.

Comment: In some other python file, are you doing `from name_of_above_file import *` OR `from name_of_above_file import Axes3D `?

Comment: Please also mention the stack trace of the error you get when you remove this line. In the stack trace you can see where it is been used.